# Code for generating an enumerated list to the right of a large curly brace

Tags: lists

Which is the code to programm this text ordering?

[image]

Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

You can use `cases` with a tabular. Load `amsmath` package.

```
\begin{align*}
\text{Formation (F)}%
\begin{cases}
    \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}} % adjust the width
        I. Assist \\
        II. Assist \\
        III. Assist word or phrase very long word or phrase very long word or phrase very long word or phrase very long word or phrase very long word or phrase very long word or phrase very long 
    \end{tabular}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I would use the capabilities of the `enumitem` package to create a compact enumerated list to the right of the large curly brace.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{7}
\subsubsection{Work breakdown in stucture}
\[ 
\text{Formation (F)}=\left\{
\begin{tabular}{p{0.7\textwidth}}  % choose width suitably
\raggedright
\begin{enumerate}[nosep, leftmargin=1.75em, label=\Roman*.]
\item Assist to seminars about numerical methods and turbulent flows
\item Assist to seminars about C++ programming
\item Assist to lectures about mathematical modeling of combustion and resolution techniques 
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabular}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you want to eliminate the vertical "overhang" of the large curly brace, you could proceed as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{7}

\subsubsection{Work breakdown in stucture}
\[ 
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\text{Formation (F)}=\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{\,} r >{\raggedright\arraybackslash} p{0.7\textwidth}}
I. & Assist to seminars about numerical methods and turbulent flows\\
II. & Assist to seminars about C++ programming\\
III. & Assist to lectures about mathematical modeling of combustion and resolution techniques \\
\end{tabular}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `*` after `Roman`? Nice!

Comment: the gap between the brace and the widest roman numeral seems relatively excessive.  space matching that between the index and the text of an item (not counting optical space added by period) would look better.  rationale: the space around the equals sign is too much narrower.  there's also excess space at the bottom of the list, maybe because of how `tabular` is handled.  also, `\raggedright`.  (don't like to be negative, because otherwise, i like this.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for these comments. I've updated the MWE to (i) reduce the separation between the large curly brace and the Roman numeral and (ii) typeset the enumerated material in ragged-right mode.

Comment: Can you do something about the gap at the bottom of the enumeration?

Comment: @Sigur - I'm afraid I have no deep insights into the syntax preferences of the creator/maintainer of the `enumitem` package. However, I suspect the command `\Roman*` is short-hand for `\Roman{enumi}` (or whatever enumeration level we may be at).

Comment: @egreg - I've provided an addendum to address your concern. The result is now more indeed more compact, but at the cost of reduced programming elegance. :-( (The 'nosep' directive of the `enumitem` package unfortunately does not appear to squash *all* vertical whitespace above and below an `enumerate` environment.) Happy New Year, by the way!!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution that automatically fills up the line, but can be adapted to a smaller width (to be used in a `center` environment) via the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\newlength{\bdlen}
\newcounter{breakdown}
\newcommand{\breakdown}[3][\columnwidth]{%
  \settowidth{\bdlen}{#2 $\left\lbrace\rule{0pt}{6\baselineskip}\right.$}%
  \par\noindent
  #2\hfil$\left\lbrace\parbox{\dimexpr(#1-\bdlen)}{%
    \setcounter{breakdown}{0}%
    \renewcommand\item{%
      \par\medskip\stepcounter{breakdown}\Roman{breakdown}.\enspace
    }%
    #3\par
    \smallskip
  }\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace${\parfillskip=0pt\par}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Word breakdown structure}

\breakdown{Formation (F)}{
  \item Assist to seminars about numerical methods and turbulent flows
  \item Assist to seminars about C++ programming
  \item Assist to lectures about mathematical modelling
        of combustion and resolution techniques
}

\begin{center}
\breakdown[.9\textwidth]{Formation (F)}{
  \item Assist to seminars about numerical methods and turbulent flows
  \item Assist to seminars about C++ programming
  \item Assist to lectures about mathematical modelling
        of combustion and resolution techniques
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. So complicated code, but very professional.

Comment: first version would look nicer without a hyphenated word; `\raggedright` would not be inappropriate.